# Delete duplicated data

Tags: mysql

How do I delete duplicated data in the `absen` table below?

> 1. field table absen (date,time,id_user)
> 2. field table employee (name,department,address,id_user)

I tried the query:

```
select absen.date,min(absen.time),max(absen.time),absen.id_user,employee.name
from absen,employee 
where absen.id_user = employee.id_user 
group by absen.tanggal having employee.id_user = '00600320' and absen.tanggal between '2015/01/01' and '2015/01/31' 
order by absen.tanggal asc
```

I want to delete all data which is not included in this query, because employees have more than one row per day.

Example :

```
2015/01/01 08:00:00 00600320
2015/01/01 08:00:08 00600320
2015/01/01 08:00:15 00600320
2015/01/01 17:10:00 00600320
2015/01/01 17:00:10 00600320
2015/01/01 17:00:12 00600320
```

I just want take up min and max from table absen and delete all between min and max.

NB : i want delete table.

Comment: I think this is not duplicate of it, the scenario here is different than there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps:

**1**.Get your data with their related `min` and `max` dates:

you can use `CONCAT` function to concat date and time.

```
select  
        t.id_user,
        min(CONCAT(t.date,' ',t.time)) mindate,
        max(CONCAT(t.date,' ',t.time)) maxdate 
from absen t
join employee on t.id_user = employee.id_user 
group by t.id_user ;
```

**2**.Remove the data which does not relates or belongs to above wanted result set.

create another `table` (or `temporary table`), insert the none duplicate data(`max` and `mins` you wanted) into it and then remove the data from original table which is not in the newly created table using `row_subquery` and finally drop the newly created table, I created another table because can not use delete and select on same table at same time:

```
create table tbl(id_user int,
                          mindate datetime,
                          maxdate datetime);
insert into tbl
select  
        t.id_user,
        min(CONCAT(t.date,' ',t.time)) mindate,
        max(CONCAT(t.date,' ',t.time)) maxdate 
from absen t
join employee on t.id_user = employee.id_user 
group by t.id_user ;

delete from absen
where 
row(id_user,
    CONCAT(date,' ',time)) not in
(select id_user,mindate from tbl
 union
 select id_user,maxdate from tbl);
drop table tbl;
```

Here is [THE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e232a/1) of what I did.